# AspectJ not weaving all classes

Tags: java, aspectj

I am using AspectJ with run time weaving. The agent is loading OK, it finds my aspect and my aop file. However my classes aren't weaved although some third party classes are weaved.

this is my aop file

```xml
<aspectj>
<weaver options="-showWeaveInfo -debug">
    <!-- only weave classes in this package -->
    <!--include within="*.*"/-->
</weaver>
<aspects>
    <aspect name="wf.core.aspects.LogInfoCallerAspect"></aspect>
</aspects>
```

What causes this?

Comment: grammar and readability

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question because you are not providing enough information to reproduce the problem. All I can see is that you have commented out your `include within` clause, i.e. you seem to include everything, which explains why 3rd party classes are woven. You should also show us the aspect code and the weaver log output.

Comment: We had a similar problem. In the aop.xml we had <include within="*.*"/> which worked fine in Windows but when tested in Linux it did not work. When i changed it to <include within="*"/> it worked just fine. May be you can have a go at it once.Assuming your Pointcut expression is fine.